# Flutter - How to know when an audio starts playing? (without user action)

Tags: flutter, audio

I have an app that starts to play audio files automatically on a specific screen.

I want to display relevant message on the screen according to the playing audio.

The problem is that every time I load the audio it takes different time for it to load, and therefore I don't know when to start displaying the message.

I want to know when the audio starts to play (no user input for that).

Code:

```
Future<int> _playAudio({required String url}) async {
    final playPosition = (_position != null &&
            _duration != null &&
            _position!.inMilliseconds > 0 &&
            _position!.inMilliseconds < _duration!.inMilliseconds)
        ? _position
        : null;
    final result = await _audioPlayer.play(url, position: playPosition);
    if (result == 1) {
      setState(() => _playerState = PlayerState.PLAYING);
      displayMessage();
    }
    _audioPlayer.setPlaybackRate();
    return result;
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: provide more information and show the code related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to `PlayerState` event of `_audioPlayer` as documented here [State Event](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers#state-event)

```
_audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((PlayerState s) => {
  print('Current player state: $s');
  setState(() => _playerState = s);
});
```

Comment: @userRM I'm glad you find this helpful. If this answer solve your issue, please don't forget to accept the answer, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
_audioPlayer.onNotificationPlayerStateChanged.listen((status) {
  status == PlayerState.PLAYING;// PLAYING,PAUSED,STARTED,COMPLETED
});
```